# How do i create a get query in nodeJS based on information contained in checkboxes

Tags: node.js, checkbox

I am trying to build an app that lets users find other users with a specific combination of skills. I ask the users to select which skills they are looking for via checkboxes but I'm not sure how to request for the status of that checkbox in my function.

My function currently is:

```
  UserInfo.find()
      .where('skill1').equals('')
      .where('skill2').equals('')
      .where('skill3').equals('')
      .limit(10)
      .then(function(doc) {
        res.render('index', {items: doc});
      });
```

It works properly if I set the equals('') to true or false but I'm not sure how to set it dynamically. My HTML code for the checkboxes is:

```
<form action="/getskills" method="get">
        <div class="input">
          <label for="skill1">Skill1</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="skill1" name="skill1" value="skill1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
          <label for="skill2">Skill2</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="skill2" name="skill2" value="skill2"/>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
          <label for="skill3">Skill3</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="skill3" name="skill3" value="skill3"/>
        </div>
  <a href="/getskills">FIND SKILL</a>
    </form>
```

How can I create and integrate a function to check the value of the checkbox and set the value of the required skill to either true or false?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an `<a>` element to perform the request to the server instead of `<input type="submit">`. Without a submit button, the elements on your form will not be submitted with the request. Modify your html to this

```html
<form action="/getskills" method="get">
  <div class="input">
    <label for="skill1">Skill1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="skill1" name="skill1" value="skill1" />
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <label for="skill2">Skill2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="skill2" name="skill2" value="skill2" />
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <label for="skill3">Skill3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="skill3" name="skill3" value="skill3" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="FIND SKILL" />
</form>
```

then in your Node.js code (I assume you are using express), you can get the checkbox values as query parameters as follows:

```js
//I'm assuming the req parameter is passed in to the express get() method
UserInfo.find()
      .where('skill1').equals(req.query.skill1)
      .where('skill2').equals(req.query.skill2)
      .where('skill3').equals(req.query.skill3)
      .limit(10)
      .then(function(doc) {
        res.render('index', {items: doc});
      });
```